# Plex can't see ZFS pool when trying to add library

Tags: 22.04, snap, zfs, plex

So I just set up a new server (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS), installed Plex via snap, and set up a raidz1 pool. I can copy files to the pool, but when I go to add a folder on it to a plex library, the pool just doesn't show up.

I've got the permissions set wide open (rwx access to everyone), but maybe I'm missing something there? I've also tried putting a symlink to the desired folder in a location Plex *can* see...but Plex sees the symlink as a file, and it's greyed out and unselectable.

Any thoughts on how to get Plex to play nice with my ZFS pool?

```
/home$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.6G  2.9M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda4       916G   19G  851G   3% /
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
efivarfs        192K  129K   59K  69% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p2  260M   37M  224M  14% /boot/efi
spa              22T  2.8G   22T   1% /spa
tmpfs           1.6G  1.7M  1.6G   1% /run/user/10

/home$ zfs list
NAME   USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
spa   33.8G  21.0T     33.8G  /spa

/home$ zfs get mountpoint 
NAME  PROPERTY    VALUE       SOURCE
spa   mountpoint  /spa        default
```

Comment: I figured that since it would "see" and let me add a folder in `/home`, putting the symlink there would be good enough; I feel unsure about throwing the symlink in the snap directory, I don't even know where i should put it.

Comment: If the symlink doesn't work, you can use a bind mount

Comment: Your df don't show any mounted ZFS filesystems. You have to create afilesystem dataset on the ZFS pool, and mount it. You can't access ZFS-pools directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying Daniel's suggestion with a bind mount. Here, I assume your homedir is `/home/marcus`.

Then, you can create a bind mount (filesystem "loop"/"replication") like this.

First, create the new mountpoint:

```
mkdir /home/marcus/spa
```

Then, create the actual bind mount:

```
sudo mount --bind /spa /home/marcus/spa
```

Now the contents of `/home/marcus/spa` should for all purposes have the same contents as `/spa`.

You can also include this in `/etc/fstab` with the following line: (the last `,ro` part can be added if you want the homedir "replica" of `/spa` to be only a read-only view).

```
/spa /home/marcus/spa none bind,ro
```

Additionally, [see here for further reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount).

Comment: This seems to have solved my problem! Plex now sees it as a usable directory, instead of not seeing it at all (like the `/spa` mountpoint) or as a broken symlink (like the...symlink.) Before I make it permanent by adding it to the fstab and forgetting about it, I want to ask if this is: a) a kludgy hack to use until I figure out a better solution, or b) probably just the solution?

Comment: I think this is the best solution if you use Plex as a Snap. If you ran Plex in Docker or as native `.deb`, it would have systemwide access, and you wouldn't need this. It's a matter of preference. 

Comment: I think I see. I'm new to using Snap, so I'll be sure to read up on the ramifications of using it vs other methods, and maybe switch. Thanks!